# PowerShell gui and the endless program loop?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

After the gui works perfectly I am stunned how to integrate it into an endless program loop.
The gui is meant to display the status of several socket-connections. So I have:

1. the gui call [PowerShell button click event scriptblock not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367794/powershell-hand-over-s-th-todo-not-working) `GenerateForm`
2. the endless loop that reacts on the orders of the gui and is stopped if the EXIT-button of the gui is clicked.

How do I do that without the gui (`GenerateForm`) called again and again?

```
do {
    # write the status lines of the gui...
} until ( <# exit-function of the gui was called #> )

#disconnect, close and dispose..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShowDialog()` method blocks until the form is eventually closed.  Therefore you need to do all your status updating as a result of events firing (inside an event handler).  Since the Sockets class seems to be lacking in events, you can set up a WinForms timer event to fire an event handler every 500 millisecs or so to check the socket status.

Comment: Is there another method than ShowDialog() that might be better to display some status variables and set some other variables to 'steer' the endless-prgram-loop?

Comment: Not really.  You need ShowDialog() because it services the windows message queue otherwise you have to pump messages with something hacky like Application.DoEvents().